How do I get the Medicare plan finder key
I am trying to get a key to the Medicare Plan Finder I've tried contacting Medicare but no answer as yet not sure if I applied in the right area. Has anyone have any success in getting one and know how to get it

Are you looking for this form? https://developer.cms.gov/finder-api/key-request.html It's  one of the first results in google when typing "Medicare Plan Finder  api key". If it's not what you're looking for, can you be more specific?

Hello, thanks for responding. I did go to that website. Unfortunately, no one answered, so I was a bit disappointed

Maybe they just don't have enough staff for answering requests in a time frame you find acceptable. Or perhaps it was some bug with the connection on your side or theirs, and they never received the message. Perhaps retry in a couple of days. There's also another contact form at the top right corner of this page: https://developer.cms.gov/. As a last resort, they also have a postal address, available at the bottom of the same page.

Hi guys, thanks for all the comments and the help you have given me. I am so eternally grateful for your help and answers. I think I may have to wait a while to see.
